# How to get the ordinary generating function for this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, algorithms, generating-functions

I came across the following sum:

$$
\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{2^k}{2^k+1}
$$

Is there a way to derive the ordinary generating function (OGF) for this sum?, i.e. given the series:

$$
A(z) = a_0 + a_1z^1 + a_2z^2 + ... +a^kz^k + ...
$$

if we have for instance $a_k=1$ for all $k \geq 0$, we have OGF $A(z)=1/(1-z)$, or if the $a_k$'s represent the harmonic numbers $H_k$ for $k \geq 0$, we have the OGF $\frac{1}{1-z}\ln{(\frac{z}{1-z})}$.

So is there a way to get the OGF where $a_k=\frac{2^k}{2^k+1}$?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question - are you asking to find $f(x)$ where $f(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{2^k}{2^k+1} x^k $?

Comment: @VVejalla, yes that's what am trying to ask, the $A(z)$ above is just like the $f(x)$ of your comment

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k+%3D+0+to+infinity+of+2%5Ek%2F%282%5Ek%2B1%29+*+x%5Ek) did not give a closed form.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that the generating function has a closed formula? A possible simplification is to try and find a closed formula for the infinite series $f(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0} x^n/(2^n+1)$, then the generating function you're looking for is $f(2x)$.

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k=1 \not= 0$, so the series diverges.

It sounds like you want to compute the ordinary generating function $$\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{2^k}{2^k+1}z^k.$$
Applying the ratio test shows that this series converges when 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|(2z)^{k+1}|}{2^{k+1}+1}\cdot\frac{2^k+1}{|(2z)^k|}=|z|<1.$$

Comment: okay, my query was not clear but I edited it... am looking for a function that approximates the divergent series, just like $\frac{1}{1-z}ln(\frac{1}{1-z})$ is the function for the divergent harmonic numbers

Comment: yes, am looking for the ordinary generating function of $2^k/(2^k+1)$, will edit my post to make it clearer